# Nested SQL query alias

Tags: sql

I have a COACHINSHOW table and TVSHOW table. In the COACHINSHOW table I have the columns COACHINSHOW, IDSHOW. In the TVSHOW table, I have IDSHOW and DATE. I am trying to do a nested query to get a list of coaches, with their attendances each month. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT J.IDCOACH, J.MONTH(DATE), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT C.IDCOACH, C.IDSHOW, T.DATE
      FROM (COACHINSHOW AS C JOIN TVSHOW AS T AS J)
      WHERE C.IDSHOW = T.IDSHOW);
```

however im not sure, where to put the alias 'AS J', at the moment I keep getting a syntax error.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using, and show some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple inner join between the two tables should work here.  Note that you most likely need to use `GROUP BY` here, since you want an aggregation over the entire table by coach and month.

```
SELECT
    c.IDCOACH,
    MONTH(t.DATE),
    COUNT(t.IDSHOW) AS num_shows_month
FROM COACHINSHOW c
LEFT JOIN TVSHOW t
    ON c.IDSHOW = t.IDSHOW
GROUP BY
    c.IDCOACH,
    MONTH(t.DATE);
```

I assume that your database has a `MONTH` function.  In practice, you probably would want to group by year *and* month, since the same month can appear in multiple years.